# Java Error with Switch Statement

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code (line 12 `switch (code)`)? It wont compile.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Switch
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please entre a province's official code abbreviation");
        String code = in.next();

        double shipCost=0.0;

        switch (code) {
            case"NS": case"NB":case"PE":
                shipCost=29.95;
                break;
            case"NL":
                shipCost=34.95;
                break;
            case"OC": case"ON":
                shipCost=24.95;
                break;
            case"MB":case"SK":
                shipCost=29.95;
                break;
            case"AB":case"BC":
                shipCost=37.95;
                break;
            case"NU":case"NT":case"YT":
                shipCost=39.95;
                break;
            default:
                shipCost=0;
        }

        System.out.println("shipping cost in "+code+"is"+shipCost);
    }
}
```

> 1 error found:
>   Flle: /Users/JamesMacBook/Downloads/Solutions_ReviewExercises/Switch.java [line: 12]
>   Error: /Users/JamesMacBook/Downloads/Solutions_ReviewExercises/Switch.java:12: incompatible types
>   found : java.lang.String
>   required: int

what is wrong with line 12 ? how can i fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: Please include code as properly formatted text _within_ the question, not as an image.

Comment: It's the Java version Luke, older Java versions don't allow Strings in switch.

Comment: please don't put links to your code, who knows where that link will take someone trying to help you. SO lets you post your code to the site

Comment: ...also don't post code as image ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you it is looking for an `int` but you provided a `String`. Java added support for switching `String`s in version 7 so make sure you have that. I'm not entirely sure how to check your java version on OSX but on windows you enter `java -version` into the command prompt.